# Seguridad a solicitudes Laravel AJAX

Tags: php, laravel, seguridad

Tengo una duda, espero y me puedan ayudar, soy algo nuevo en laravel y estoy haciendo un sistema en donde estoy usando Ajax
La cosa esta así

Este es un ejemplo de la forma en que lo estoy haciendo

Tengo una ruta llamada "host:8000/personas"

La cual su método index me regresa una vista donde se mostraran un listado de todas las personas que tengo registradas, cada una con un botón
Si oprimo ese botón, mediante ajax hago una consulta a la ruta

"infopersonas/{idpersona}"

esta ruta como ya dije,se manda a llamar mediante ajax y se muestra la información de dicha persona en la pantalla, así con todos los botones, cada que lo oprima, se muestra la información.

Algo similar lo hago en distintos módulos, uso una ruta para mostrar la vista y dentro de las vistas con ajax mando a llamar información dinamicamente

Mi pregunta es ¿Esta bien hacerlo así?, es que he visto algunos ejemplos de sistemas donde la mayoría de las veces sus rutas únicamente regresan vistas, muy poco regresan el json como tal

En caso de que así sea, como se solucionaría que alguien mal intencionado logre interceptar la ruta
y vea la información asi

host:8000/infousuario/1

host:8000/infousuario/2

host:8000/infousuario/3

de esta forma podrá ver el json que regresa

Por cierto, ya tengo implementado la autenticación, las rutas están protegidas, pero como es un sistema de libre login aun así podrían obtener esas rutas y estarían logueados

¿Se puede bloquear para que esas rutas se accedan unicamente desde el sistema y no ponerlas directas en el navegador o algun otro programa de solicitudes?

Espero y puedan orientarme, muchas gracias

Comment: Deberias usar siempre https para evitar que lean las transacciones que hacen tus usuarios,  y tambien validar con un token cada request

Comment: Y en caso de un inyección por el codigo fuente que proporcionan los navegadores?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías verificar que la solicitud sea mediante ajax
Por ejemplo:

```
public function infopersonas(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        return "JSON";
    }
    return "HTTP";
}
```